# SOQL Parent-to-child relationship query fetching Contacts and EDA child Addresses

Tags: soql, education-data-architecture

I'm trying to retrieve a Salesforce `Contact` and all their EDA `Address` records.  The Contact lookup field details in the Address object, lists the Child Relationship Name as `Addresses`
[image: Parent Contact Custom field]

Following Salesforce's documentation on Parent-to-child relationship queries [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects):

> Parent-to-child relationship queries do not use dot notation:

```sql
SELECT LastName__c,
  (
    SELECT LastName__c
    FROM Daughters__r
  )
FROM Mother__c
```

I ran the following SOQL:

```sql
SELECT LastName,
(
    SELECT Name FROM Addresses__r
 )
from Contact WHERE Id = '003f400001XaiGAAAZ'
```

which fails with the following error

```
ERROR at Row:3:Column:22
Didn't understand relationship 'Addresses__r' in FROM part of query call. 
If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the 
'__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or 
the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Can someone point out how I can change my query to make it valid SOQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to query with the managed package's namespace prepended to the relationship name, when the relationship is packaged:

```
SELECT LastName,
(
    SELECT Name FROM hed__Addresses__r
 )
from Contact WHERE Id = '003f400001XaiGAAAZ'
```